# How does springMVC asynchronous improve performance

Tags: java, spring-mvc, asynchronous

all.It is said that, using asynchronous can improve performance when concurrency level is high.
So I do the test in my server, but it seems that when I use asynchronous the performance becomes even worse, I hope someone can help me.
I write two methods as follows:

first one:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/presuretest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public JSONObject presureTest() throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail("XXXX@XXX.com");
        return userService.getUser(user);//the getUser method now is just Thread.sleep(500);
    }
```

the other:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/asyncpresuretest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
     public Callable<JSONObject> asyncpresureTest() throws Exception {
            return new Callable<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public JSONObject call() throws Exception {
                    User user = new User();
                    user.setEmail("xxxx@xxxxx.com");
                    return userService.getUser(user);//The same as presureTest() method;
                }

            };
        }
```

What the methods do now are both sleep 500ms,the different is one using asynchronous,while the other don't.

Then I use ab test to test them,here is the result:
1. normal method

```
./ab -c 600 -n 600 http://52.193.80.222/presuretest

Concurrency Level:      600
Time taken for tests:   2.227 seconds
Complete requests:      600
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      112200 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    269.44 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2226.826 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       3.711 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          49.20 [Kbytes/sec] received


./ab -c 600 -n 600 http://52.193.80.222/asyncpresuretest

Concurrency Level:      600
Time taken for tests:   3.445 seconds
Complete requests:      600
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      112200 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    174.15 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       3445.252 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       5.742 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          31.80 [Kbytes/sec] received


./ab -c 700 -n 700 http://52.193.80.222/asyncpresuretest

Concurrency Level:      700
Time taken for tests:   2.682 seconds
Complete requests:      700
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      130900 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    261.04 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2681.588 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       3.831 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          47.67 [Kbytes/sec] received


./ab -c 700 -n 700 http://52.193.80.222/presuretest

Concurrency Level:      700
Time taken for tests:   2.325 seconds
Complete requests:      700
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      130900 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    301.09 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2324.909 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       3.321 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          54.98 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

I added the level to 900

```
./ab -c 900 -n 900 http://52.193.80.222/presuretest

Concurrency Level:      900
Time taken for tests:   3.761 seconds
Complete requests:      900
Failed requests:        94
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 47, Length: 0, Exceptions: 47)
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      159511 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    239.31 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       3760.847 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       4.179 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          41.42 [Kbytes/sec] received

./ab -c 900 -n 900 http://52.193.80.222/asyncpresuretest

    Concurrency Level:      900
Time taken for tests:   3.769 seconds
Complete requests:      900
Failed requests:        164
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 82, Length: 0, Exceptions: 82)
Write errors:           0
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    238.80 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       3768.787 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       4.188 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          39.64 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

So, I doubt does it really work?

```
Now, I move the callback to service.In my UserServiceImpl.java,I add method:



 public Callable<JSONObject> getUserAsync(final User user) throws Exception {
        //System.out.println("service in thread name is :" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return new Callable<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public JSONObject call() throws Exception {
                //System.out.println("callback in thread name is :" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                return null;
            }

        };
    }
```

and no midifycation for getUser method.

And I modify the controller methods like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/presuretest_v1.0", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public JSONObject presureTest() throws Exception {
    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail("670271826@qq.com");
    // Thread.sleep(2000);
    //System.out.println("controller in thread name is :" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return userService.getUser(user);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/asyncpresuretest_v1.0", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Callable<JSONObject> asyncpresureTest() throws Exception {
    //System.out.println("controller in thread name is :" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail("670271826@qq.com");
    return userService.getUserAsync(user);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous is little more complicated, than just wrapping your call in Callable, and expecting a performance boost.

In your case the part that should be asynchronous is

```
    userService.getUser(user)
```

Here you are **waiting** for DB response, which is a main bottle neck. What you did has just increased processing complexity of the request on a server, without giving any performance benefits.

If you want to have advantages of asynchronous processing, it should be embodied in your application and you need to change your code, and style of writing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I hava modify the question . wish you can check it...cause it seems does not work..

Comment: Why did you expect changes? By adding sleep you are just making things more obvious, but keep them the same, effectively you are stating costs of execution that are hidden. There must be no waits or sleep in your code, that is the point of asynchronous processing. Try DeferredResult and ScheduledExecutorService. It's hard to get it right first, second, theerd .... time, so it's perfectly fine, to have those bumps on the road.